# issue in RepeatButton in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, repeatbutton

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_remove" Height="46" Margin="234,119,225,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" GotFocus="txt_remove_GotFocus"/>
    <RepeatButton x:Name="rbtn_remove" Content="Remove" Delay="500" Interval="100"  Margin="283.667,183,282.333,222" RenderTransformOrigin="0.667,0.854" Click="rbtn_remove_Click" />                  
</Grid>
```

code In c#

```
public partial class Repeate : Window
{
    Control GetTextbox;

    public Repeate()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent(); 

    }

    private void rbtn_remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

         TextBox GetInstance = GetTextbox as TextBox;

        if (GetTextbox != null)
        {

            string _CurrentValue = GetInstance.Text;
            var _CareIndex = GetInstance.CaretIndex;

            if (_CareIndex > 0)
            {
                string _Backspace = _CurrentValue.Remove(_CareIndex - 1, 1);
                GetInstance.Text = _Backspace;
                GetInstance.Focus();
                GetInstance.CaretIndex = _CareIndex - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private void txt_remove_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetTextbox = (Control)sender;
    }

}
```

With above code i can get the result below.

[image: RepeatButton]

If i click remove button, the textbox value clear.But If i click and hold remove button,It is **not remove the textbox value repeatedly**.

Answer (score 2):

everything is good enough to do the work you want to do. but the focus() method call on Getinstance. is making the diffrance.

just remove .

```
GetInstance.Focus();
```

will work.

Comment: It is ok.But cursor should be visible when i remove the textbox value repeatedly. what should i do for that.

Comment: focusing on instance will change the behavior of reapet button as this loose the active focus. what you can do is focus the textbox when you release focus from button